# How do you get the postal_code using the Geocoder gem in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: rails-geocoder

I installed the GeoCoder gem for my Ruby on Rails project and am trying to get zip codes for the cities but the `postal_code` is always nil.  All of the cities I've put in like San Jose, CA and Seattle, WA produce a nil for the `postal_code`.

I'm running these example queries in my rails console:

```
Geocoder.search("San Jose, CA").first.postal_code
```

A workaround I found was to run the following but it makes 2 calls which goes against the service quota:

```
Geocoder.search(Geocoder.search("Seattle, WA").first.coordinates).first.postal_code
```

Is there a better syntax to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Geocoder gem to find postal code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935011/ruby-geocoder-gem-to-find-postal-code)

Answer (score 2):

Try out this gem [Area zip](http://jonathanvingiano.com/area/). It makes one call. you would do some thing like this to get the zip code

```
 "San Jose, CA".to_zip
```